# How to upload mp3 files

Tags: php

Im trying to get a form to upload mp3 or certain image files to a folder.
Using below code I can upload the image files ok, but when i try to upload an mp3 i get the error `Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\recordlabel\inc\soundclips.php on line 6` and the code echos `invalid file` from my else block. can anyone offer assistance?

```
 $allowedExts = array("mp3", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $extension = end($temp);

 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
   {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

      if (file_exists("../soundclips/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
      else
      {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
         "../soundclips/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
         echo "Stored in: " . "../soundclips/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
   }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

And this is my form

```
<form class='form1' action='../inc/soundclips.php' method='post'     
                                                   enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $pid; ?>"/>
   <b>Add Soundclip For <i><?php echo $e;?></i> </b> 
   <?php echo"<divclass='editimage'>";
   echo "<img class='resizedimage' src='{$row['image']}' />";
   echo"</div>";?><br /> 
   <b>Song</b><br /><input type=text size='60' name='asong' /><br />
   <input name='file' type="file" id="file"  /><br />
   <input type='submit' name='add' value='Add Soundclip' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your mp3 file cannot be uploaded, so it is missing in `$_FILES` array. That might be due to its size compared to image files.

Please check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings from your `php.ini` and allow a greater size than your mp3 file.

Comment: i just did that, and the same thing still happens!

Comment: did you change the values or was it already greater than mp3 file size?

Comment: i changed the vales, both to 30m

Comment: did you restart your web server then?

Comment: doh! no i didnt! it works now after the restart. Thanks, accepting your answer.