# Sending MP3 file to server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I'm writng a simple form for upload file to server. I can send any file without mp3, I don't know why.
add2.php:

```
{
    $max_size = 104857600;
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ($_FILES['plik']['size'] > $max_size) {
            echo 'Error! File is too big!';
        } else {
            echo 'I have file, name: '.$_FILES['plik']['name'];
            $nazwa= $_FILES['plik']['name'];

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (name) values ('{$nazwa}') ");

            echo '<br/>';
            if (isset($_FILES['plik']['type'])) {
                echo 'Typ: '.$_FILES['plik']['type'].'<br/>';
            }

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name'],
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/music/'.$_FILES['plik']['name']);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error with sending file!';
    }
```

When i try to send mp3 i get "Error with sending file!".

EDIT:

```
<form action="add2.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="plik"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send file"/>
</form>';
```

Comment: Where's your code for uploading?  My guess is you don't have the encoding type.  Also, your code is terribly insecure.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid SQL injection attacks.  Don't let users specify the names of files on your desk... and certainly don't keep user-uploaded files within your web server's document root.  Someone could upload `something-evil.php` and run whatever they want.

Comment: i insert code with form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on my machine and see:

Looks like your mp3 file cannot be uploaded, so it is missing in `$_FILES` array. That might be due to its size compared to image files.

Please check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings from your `php.ini` and allow a greater size than your mp3 file.

Font: [How to upload mp3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893441/how-to-upload-mp3-files)

Comment: For those ones who reads this:   `$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3";` is the array to use for this case scenario (given that you have fixed your php.ini memory issues).