# Uploaded mp3 files by php are corrupted

Tags: php, file

I've written a PHP script that uploads a mp3 file from user file input, the uploader worked fine but I went to check the directory where the files are uploaded there, I tried to play a mp3 file and it didn't work because it says it's corrupted even Filename and File size are matched.

Here is my php script:

```
//Get submitted data by user
//This is blob
    if (isset($_POST['mp3file'])) {
    $mp3 = $_POST['mp3file'];
    } else {
    $mp3 = '';
    }
//Normal string     
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
    $name = '';
    }


//Write mp3 file
    if ($mp3) { 
    $file1 = UPLOAD_DIR . $name . "_" . uniqid() . '.mp3';
    $success = file_put_contents($file1, $mp3);
    }

//Output a URL where is saved.
$locator = $file1;


//Display a text, otherwise if error happened.
print $locator ? $file1 : 'Could not save the file!';
```

Comment: the problem here is that you are not taking the file correctly, use $_FILES for the mp3 instead of $_POST.

Comment: @MichaelTétreault doesn't $_FILES accept this data form? https://i.imgur.com/kvT5DFc.png

Comment: I cant see it since i'm behind a proxy at the office that is blockig this site.

Comment: This image basically shows a source in text in form data via network in console:

**mp3file:** blob:http://localhost/360ed496-f9a2-4f3d-9492-8c33fb3903cf

**name:** Rock

Btw: This stackoverflow uses imgur for uploading images, I don't know why your office blocks imgur which is used to upload the pictures without cost.

Comment: Give a read at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893441/how-to-upload-mp3-files

Comment: @MichaelTétreault Unfortunately I only can receive blob URL and file input does not have name that requires a parameter like $_FILES["thisName"] do you know how to get default name even name is not declared?

Comment: in your form tag, are you using this attribute:  enctype="multipart/form-data" - then see if you can read the $_FILES array

Comment: @PHPology I can't edit HTML form since it's closed and external, I only receive blob uri data and that's all